# Sum elements of sub array that have the same keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<?php 
$A = array(
        'A'=>array('a'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1
                                'v2'=>2
                                'v3'=>3

                                ),
                  'b'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1
                                'v2'=>2 
                                'v3'=>3                                
                                )
                   ),
        'B'=>array('a'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1
                                'v2'=>2
                                'v3'=>3

                                ),
                     'b'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1
                                'v2'=>2
                                'v3'=>3                                
                                )
                   ),
        ...
        );

=>$total= array('a'=>array(
                                'v1'=>2
                                'v2'=>4
                                'v3'=>6

                                ),
             'b'=>array(
                                'v1'=>2
                                'v2'=>4 
                                'v3'=>6  
?>
```

It works but not a generic way.

```
$total_av1 = $A['A']['a']['v1'] + $A['B']['a']['v1'];
$total_av2 = $A['A']['a']['v2'] + $A['B']['a']['v2'];
$total_av3 = $A['A']['a']['v3'] + $A['B']['a']['v3'];


$total_bv1 = $A['A']['b']['v1'] + $A['B']['b']['v1'];
$total_bv2 = $A['A']['b']['v2'] + $A['B']['b']['v2'];
$total_bv3 = $A['A']['b']['v3'] + $A['B']['b']['v3'];

$total = array(
                "a"=>array($total_av1,$total_av2,$total_av3),
               "b"=>array($total_bv1,$total_bv2,$total_bv3)               
               );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($A);               
print_r($total);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like a loop?

Comment: Do you know beforehand the structure of the source array? I.e. is `['A']['a']` and `['A']['b']` always exists in the source array?

Comment: in general A(a,b),B(a,b),C(a,b) .. and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go fancy (or really *hates* `foreach`):

Source Array:

```
$A = array(
        'Z'=>array('d'=>array(
                                'v1'=>10,
                                'v2'=>20,
                                'v3'=>30

                                )
                   ),
        'A'=>array('a'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1,
                                'v2'=>2,
                                'v3'=>3

                                ),
                  'b'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1,
                                'v2'=>2,
                                'v3'=>3                                
                                )
                   ),
        'B'=>array('a'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1,
                                'v2'=>2,
                                'v3'=>3

                                ),
                     'b'=>array(
                                'v1'=>1,
                                'v2'=>2,
                                'v3'=>3                                
                                )
                   ),
        'C'=>array('a'=>array(
                                'v1'=>9,
                                'v2'=>8,
                                'v3'=>7

                                ),
                     'b'=>array(
                                'v1'=>6,
                                'v2'=>5,
                                'v3'=>4                                
                                )
                   )
        );
```

Procedure:

```
$total=array_reduce($A,function(&$r,$v){
    array_walk($v,function($val,$key)use(&$r){
        if(!isset($r[$key])) $r[$key]=array();
        array_walk($val,function($vv,$vk)use(&$r,$key){
            if(!isset($r[$key][$vk])) $r[$key][$vk]=0;
            $r[$key][$vk]+=$vv;
        });
    });
    return $r;
},array());
print_r($total);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [d] => Array
        (
            [v1] => 10
            [v2] => 20
            [v3] => 30
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [v1] => 11
            [v2] => 12
            [v3] => 13
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [v1] => 8
            [v2] => 9
            [v3] => 10
        )

)
```

Notice that I purposely add an irregular `$A['Z']` to demonstrate the procedure.

Requires PHP >=5.3. [**Live demo**](http://3v4l.org/SmdTY)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same.

```
$a['v1'] = $A['A']['a']['v1'] + $A['B']['a']['v1'];
$a['v2'] = $A['A']['a']['v2'] + $A['B']['a']['v2'];
$a['v3'] = $A['A']['a']['v3'] + $A['B']['a']['v3'];

$b['v1'] = $A['A']['b']['v1'] + $A['B']['b']['v1'];
$b['v2'] = $A['A']['b']['v2'] + $A['B']['b']['v2'];
$b['v3'] = $A['A']['b']['v3'] + $A['B']['b']['v3'];

$total= array('a'=> $a, 'b'=> $b);

echo "Not so generic <pre>";
print_r($total);
echo "</pre>";
```

To make it generic, you'll need to nest some loops that use the keys correctly.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($A['A']['a']) + 1; $i++) {
    $total2['a']['v'.$i] = $A['A']['a']['v'.$i] + $A['B']['a']['v'.$i];
    $total2['b']['v'.$i] = $A['A']['b']['v'.$i] + $A['B']['b']['v'.$i];
}
echo "Sort of generic <pre>";
print_r($total2);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: it not generic ,example when you have A,B,C,D,,, with your code will add manually by hardcode.in your code there are A and B.